# Responsive Text block on top of image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like to place a responsive text block on top of an image that I have set up based on [this dated tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/) and amended based on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415994/how-to-create-responsive-text-on-top-of-an-image).

Unfortunately there appears to be a couple of bugs. the span.spacer used to create padding either side of the line break appears taller than the rest of the text block, and I also think it is causing the text to not align left correctly. The development page [can be viewed here](http://davidkneale.com/wc/borneo/). You can see a taller black block at the end of the first line of text, and a taller black block at the beginning of the second line.

The CSS i'm using is

```
}
.image { 
position: relative; 
width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

.image h2 { 
position: absolute; 
bottom: 20px;
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
text-shadow: none;
}
h2 span { 
color: #fff; 
font-size: 110%;
width: 40%;
line-height: 110%;
padding: 0 20px;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
h2 span.spacer {
padding:0 5px;
}
```

The HTML is

```
<div class="image">

<img alt="Trekking" src="http://davidkneale.com/wc/wp-content/uploads/borneo_trek_mock.jpg" />
<h2><span>Trekking:<span class='spacer'></span><br />
<span class='spacer'></span>It's a Jungle Out There</span></h2>
</div>
```

Any advice on a fix for this or a better way to do it much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is becase you have span element in another span element (they are overlaid) and CSStyle is applied to both.
I think you can modify selector to: h2>span {...},

You can use one span element for each line (each with diferent look):

```
<h2>
<span class="big">Trekking:</span>
<br>
<span>It's a Jungle Out There</span>
</h2>


h2 span {
color: #fff;
font-size: 110%;
line-height: normal;
padding: 0 20px;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
display: inline-block;;
}
h2 span.big {
font-size:130%;
}
```

Width 40% was too short.

Comment: Thanks very much for that! I removed the `<br>` between the 2 spans and it removed a large gap. Great fix!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the increased height is the span within a span causing the font-size 110% to be applied twice. Set font-size 100% on the spacer.

You also probably want an increased line height (more like 140% than 110% with the font you're using), and a spacer padding of 10px to match the 20px of the start/end. It does feel like there should be a simpler way to do this!

Comment: A simpler way: http://dracos.co.uk/temp/so22585470/ - put each line of the h2 in a span, and just float/clear left the spans. No spacers needed, no line height either :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this tutorial is quite outdated – I would not bother with that “spacer-span” mumbo-jumbo at all.

And while it is not possible to have a horizontal padding applied to each line of an inline element (it’ll only be applied before the first and after the last line) – it is possible to use `box-shadow` to achieve a similar *effect* (as long as only a background color is required, and not f.e. an image).

```
<div>
<img src="http://davidkneale.com/wc/wp-content/uploads/borneo_trek_mock.jpg">
    <h2><span>Trekking:&#10;It’s a Jungle Out There</span></h2>
</div>

div { position:relative; }
img { display:block; max-width:100%; }
h2 { position:absolute; bottom:0; left:.5em; white-space:pre; line-height:1.333; }
h2 span { padding:.125em 0 .125em .25em; background:rgba(0,0,0,.75); color:#fff;
          box-shadow:-.5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75), .5em 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75); }
```

See it here in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FXJEL/

I gave the `span` element a `padding-left` here to have the first line of text be slightly moved to the right, as in your example – assuming that is a desired effect; if not, simply remove it.

And instead of using a `<br>` to break the text into two lines, I used `&#10;` for a line break character, and `white-space:pre` to have it displayed as such. But feel free to change that back to using a `br` element if that seems more convenient.

The `span` element inside the `h2` is necessary here to have an inline element, because only that will behave like this regarding the element dimensions; under normal conditions, one could of course make the `h2` display as inline, but that does not work here, because the `h2` is positioned absolutely, and that “overwrites” `display:inline`, and one would end up with a box that is as wide as the whole text.