# Using bootstrap - text to match parent div width on browser resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap and I have a background img that is aligned to the center of timer-background. I want subtext and big-text width to change to be 100% of timer-background so that I can center align them.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='col-xs-4'>
    <div class='borders timer-background'>
            <span class='subtext'>june</span><span class="big-text">05</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.timer-background {
     background: url(../assets/timer_background.png) center center no-repeat;
}

.big-text {
     font-family: 'Tulpen One', cursive;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-size: 120px;
   }
```

[image: date image]

Comment: You want the `span` width to be 100% or the font size to scale to fill the space?

Comment: I wanted the font to scale to fill the space. I got it working using width:inherit; position:absolute;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few Stackoverflow articles that I think will point you in the right direction.

> [How can I vertically center text over a responsive image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773647/how-can-i-vertically-center-text-over-a-responsive-image)
>
> [How to create responsive text on top of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415994/how-to-create-responsive-text-on-top-of-an-image)
>
> [Text vertically and horizontally centered over a responsive image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818976/text-vertically-and-horizontally-centered-over-a-responsive-image)

Hope this helps the cause.

Comment: I eventually did solve this but thanks for the links they are super helpful!